# Add link to most recent activity of a question

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, recent-activity, hyperlinks

Currently in the front page, if a question is modified, answered, commented etc. the last user to affect the question appears:

> [image]

Which is great.

The problem is when I want to know what that user did.

For instance, for very popular questions I know it will be the last answer in page ... 16 etc.

For comments or edits I copy the user name ( ctr+c ) click on the question, and then ctrl+f to find them.

I think it would be nice if I can have a link to what that user did on that question to see it directly. I guess a link in the "time" would do, just like in the editing history.

> [image]

---

I have just realized this functionality is half done in the "Recent" tab in the user profile which actually has the "link to recent activity" functionality already.

Comment: I agree - great idea!

Comment: "symbolic +1" (because I can't up-vote yet) This would be really usefull, sometimes I interpret erroneously who whas asking the question.

Comment: @JeffAtwood: Thanks, man! Another nice addition.

Comment: Indeed, nicely implemented. Right now, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37328/my-godits-full-of-unicorns/?lastactivity links to the edit of Marc at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37328/my-godits-full-of-unicorns/38067#38067, while actually a more recent answer than Marc's answer exists. But indeed: that more recent answer is older than the most recent *edit* to that older answer. Thumps up, this works fine!

Comment: Awesome. Actually this was implemented exactly the way I thought!! Thank you!

Comment: This is a _great_ feature, but it's sneaky.  I would never have considered clicking on that gray text if I hadn't been lucky enough to see this post on Meta's front page.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I wouldn't mind seeing the little activity listing right there say some of the following:

- Answered by [Username] 5 min ago
- Question revised by [Username] 15 min ago
- Answer revised by [Username] 7 min ago
- etc. etc. etc.

Sometimes I look at the little activity indicator there and I think that was the person who asked the question, so it can lead to some confusion.

Comment: Creating a direct link to the action is useful too.  Suppose you see: "Answer commented by[Jeff Atwood] 20 sec ago"  on a question which you remember was very active 4 months ago.  Then you really want to see what did Jeff commented ( or any other user you are interested in ) You open the question and you see nothing at first sight because this was a very active question it has 15 pages. Eventually you may see what the user did, in page 2 or 3. By providing the link you can see what the contribution was.

Comment: I have no problem with it being a link along with the text.

Answer (score 4):

I can't tell you how many times I've clicked the name, thinking it would take me to the most recent post.

Comment: Well at least I'm not the only one.

Answer (score 4):

To illustrate the new click-through functionality:

---

[image]

---

Note: 21 min vs. 44 min is due to the way the screen captures were made; normally the maximum difference is 1 min.

Comment: Implementation note: the way it was implemented may cause some noise to some users, because the link actually takes you to the "most" recent activity. This is the related question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40243/recent-activity-bug-or-feature

Comment: note that this also works on the question page if you click the date on the sidebar for last activity.

Answer (score 2):

While this would be useful, I think that introducing a new answer sort order, "active", that puts the latest activity at the top would be a better solution. That way if there are multiple recent updates you can see them all. I suggested this on UserVoice a while ago but it didn't take.

Comment: The problem with that is, you have to click twice, once in the question, once in the "active" tab.  Not really what I would like to do ( if am I to know that that user did ) ....

Comment: By default, I sort by "newest", and if "active" ever appears I would sort by that instead. But the suggestions aren't mutually incompatible, so ideally we could get both.

Answer (score 0):

If they're worried about this being making the UI look too busy, perhaps make it "hidden" by not changing the look of it.  That way, those of us whose reflexes have been trained by Infopop or other forums will be rewarded for our instincts, and the interface still looks clean.

While you're at it, if you could add in this, [Make Activity Description in 'Activity' Tab More Descriptive](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10521/make-activity-description-in-activity-tab-more-descriptive), that would be greeaaaaat.