# Make Activity Description in 'Activity' Tab More Descriptive

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, user-interface

Right now, each question in the 'Active' tab is followed by the text "Modified [n] minutes ago by [author]".

It would be nice if the "Modified [n] minutes ago..." text could be more descriptive such as:

- "**Asked** [n] minutes ago by..." - for **new questions**
- "**Answered** [n] minutes ago by..." - for **new answers**
- "**Modified** [n] minutes ago by..." - for **edited posts**

...so we can better decide if it is worth following a link.

Comment: If this happen to be implemented ever, could you also: "Add the fuctionality of 'Recent' in user profile into the main page" => http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4391/add-link-to-most-recent-activity-of-a-question/23659

Comment: Why are people closing this as too localized? It certainly hasn't been changed and the Active tab does still exist...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good idea, but we just don't have that information there without running more queries, which I don't want to do in the listing page.

Comment: Have you considered this *related* feature where links in the 'Activite' tab bring you to the *actual activity* (the modified post) rather than a linking to the original question? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10523/in-the-active-tab-listing-link-to-each-posts-actual-activity . This request came up on Stack Exchange, too. It's so much more obvious how useful this would be on the smaller sites of Stack Exchange (in comparison to a huge site like SO where it is much less likely you will try to follow *everything*).

Comment: Wouldn't it just be a matter of putting the information there without needing to run more queries?

Answer (score 8):

I love this idea and would add

- **Retagged** ... ago

to the list, for questions that were merely retagged.

Jeff apparently liked the idea, too, but [declined it for technical reasons](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10521/make-activity-description-in-activity-tab-more-descriptive/24115#24115). Since this is already almost 2 years ago, it would be great if the idea would be reconsidered. As Cawas commented, the technical problems could be solved by adding one more data field where the necessary information can be put so that additional queries wouldn't be required.

Answer (score 0):

I have updated my userscript and it now covers the active tab. ([Related post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/182737/209357))

[**Stack Activity**: Last activity of every question on the homepage and active tab](https://stackapps.com/questions/4134/stack-activity-last-activity-of-every-question-on-the-homepage)

> Here's a screenshot of the active tab on Meta Stack Overflow with the userscript:
>
> [image: meta]