# In the 'Active' Tab Listing, Link to Each Posts' Actual Activity

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, user-interface, question-lists, last-activity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Add link to most recent activity of a question.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4391/add-link-to-most-recent-activity-of-a-question)

The 'Active' tab includes a list of questions that have new or edited answers.

It would be *really* nice if the text ("Modified 2 minutes ago by..." ) was a link to the **actual activity** (i.e. a **direct link** to the new or edited answer).

In active questions, there is no easy (or reliable) way to find the newest "activity" in the question thread... at least not without a lot of hunting and scrolling.

A *direct link* would show us the newest stuff being posted to the system as it happens.

*Note: This is a followup to my [last question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10521/make-activity-description-in-activity-tab-more-descriptive)...*

Comment: Voted to reopen: this is neither completed, nor a duplicate of that question.

Comment: @Jon: It seems that this _is_ now completed. The "modified" is not part of the link, but the "... ago" links to the recent activity. I don't know when this was implemented, but I think it didn't work when I tested it several months ago.

Answer (score 0):

You could also have it link to the new [Timeline](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36303/feedback-request-new-timeline-question-view) feature.