# Could "modified x mins ago" be a link?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, user-interface, last-activity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In the 'Active' Tab Listing, Link to Each Posts' Actual Activity](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10523/in-the-active-tab-listing-link-to-each-posts-actual-activity)

On the home page clicking the modified time acts as a link.

Can this be extended to other pages displaying lists of questions. (Ones with the display format "modified x mins ago").

An example of such a page would be [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server)

Comment: That question was improperly closed as a duplicate. I have voted to reopen again.