# Add option to not-bump question when editing/answering

Tags: feature-request, edits, answers, bump

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Is there a way to edit a question without bumping it to the front page?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23241/is-there-a-way-to-edit-a-question-without-bumping-it-to-the-front-page)
>   [Closes / Edits Should Not Bump Questions on “Recent” List](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28994/closes-edits-should-not-bump-questions-on-recent-list)
>   [Is “I’m tired of seeing this get bumped” a valid reason to lock a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31211/is-im-tired-of-seeing-this-get-bumped-a-valid-reason-to-lock-a-post)

There have been [a lot of `[feature-request]`s to make more actions bump a question to the front page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=feature+request+bump).

Given the fact that there have been some questions/[answers that have been locked because of too much activity](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/26518#26518), and that there are [others](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34181/stack-overflow-ad-gallery) [that](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37825/what-is-a-bad-feature-of-stack-overflow) [come up](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-overflow-clones) [every once in a while](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work-on-stack-overflow), could we have an option to to a non-bumping edit and to add a non-bumping question?

May be it would not be appropriate on SO, as the amount of questions already takes care of this problem, but on Meta, well, is easier to get on the nerves of people.

Note that something similar [has been already proposed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23241/is-there-a-way-to-edit-a-question-without-bumping-it-to-the-front-page).

Comment: @State of the Union: and it seems like I'm unable to proofread the title before posting.

Comment: More like you had ads on your mind.

Comment: @random: hey, I come from the ad gallery question, so it could be that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One of the *purposes* of bumping is allowing users to review new content. Without automatic bumping, harmful content can be added without the scrutiny of community self-moderation. Bad idea.

Comment: This. Bumping isn't a guarantee that malicious actions will be caught, but they make it a *possibility* - and it should always be a possibility.

Comment: Good point against this. Would a mod-only option be more sensible?

Comment: Yup. The mod-only option is called "locking" and it's brilliant... ;-P

Comment: @Shog9: you know what I'm talking about. Locking eliminates any possibility of discussion/commenting on the locked post.

Comment: @TheBiChe: Yup, and bumping brings in more people to discuss/comment - so my feeling remains, if attention is desired then bumping is good, otherwise locking fits the bill.

Answer (score -7):

I have a better idea. Stop using the front page so much. Then it won't bother you at all.

Comment: I'm not the one bothered, I'm asking this so the ones that *are* bothered **and** have locking powers don't lock answers just for the heck of it.

Comment: And I am saying they should read this answer and take it to heart.

Comment: @the "I'm asking this so the ones that are bothered" - please refer those that are aggrieved to this site, and in particular to this question, so they may make their own case.

Comment: @Pollyanna: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31211/is-im-tired-of-seeing-this-get-bumped-a-valid-reason-to-lock-a-post

Comment: @The - Oh good, the discussion has already occurred.  I'll vote to close as dupe.  Thanks!