# Edits to deleted posts shouldn't bump them

Tags: feature-request, edits, deleted-questions, deleted-answers, bump

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Stop an edited deleted answer from bumping the question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42066/stop-an-edited-deleted-answer-from-bumping-the-question)

I just edited a deleted answer of mine to add an explanation of why I deleted it. The question got bumped to the front page. At best, that's confusing for non-10k users (who won't see any recent activity if they view the question) and a waste of time for 10k users (who will see new content, but nothing really useful).

I understand that we ["don't want content added to [the] system without people noticing"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28994/closes-edits-should-not-bump-questions-on-recent-list/29013#29013), but edits to a deleted post hardly qualify as addition of content. Therefore, edits to deleted posts shouldn't bump them. Instead, the system should bump when a post is undeleted, if it doesn't do that already.