# Can we add 'asked', 'answered', 'edited' text to each question featured on the front page?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, user-interface, bump, active

When I'm looking down the front page on [dba.se](https://dba.stackexchange.com/), I often wish I could tell at a glance what happened to the question to bump it there. Sometimes it is obvious from looking at the number of answers, other times you have to follow a link to find out if it has been edited or if an answer has been added or updated.

I'm guessing this is just as applicable on other SE sites - this is the kind of thing I'm suggesting:

[image]

A couple of suggestions from the comments that might be good:

- To reduce clutter the word 'ago' could be removed at the same time.
- The new text could be visible only to established users - ie users who are likely to be reviewing/editing and would benefit from seeing at a glance what kind of change has occurred.

Comment: Good suggestion, but I suspect the cost is pretty high.. let the devs decide though.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I can't agree about cost.  While I don't know *exactly* how the data is stored, I imagine it's just a `top 1` on a highly optimized index on the last updated/modified/answered fields.  Same for the cache.  But, yes, it's up to SE to decide.

Comment: Thanks @casper we should also consider the risk of cluttering the list, guess not everyone will be happy with such change.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd No downvotes yet, doesn't seem like anyone is unhappy with the prospect *yet*.  Also, reputation score could be removed from that list to make space.  It doesn't really *help* with anything.  You shouldn't care if questions are added/edited/answered based on reputation.

Comment: @casper actually the reputation display help me notice potential non answers - seeing 1 rep user modifying question with over 100 views is usually suspicious. 50% of the times, it should be a comment.

Comment: @casperOne I wondered about suggesting removing the word 'ago'?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I can see how that's helpful, but it's a secondary usage of the front page, not the primary usage (or at least, not the intended usage).  If anything, I'd say those edits should be in a separate list that's slated for review.  Chances are if that happens, the new `/review` queue is going to pick that up (at least I'd hope so).

Comment: @JackDouglas I can get behind that.  Seems very redundant; if you think that time is indicative of something that's going to happen in the future, then you've got bigger problems on your hands.

Comment: @casperOne It may be there to avoid tiny links like "1s" - which wouldn't be necessary if other text was added.

Comment: What would the word be for questions poked by Community? *poked*?

Comment: @AndriyM 'bumped'?

Comment: +1 But this UI change should only be for users of a certain rep.

Comment: This would be nice indeed; I often click into a question thinking it was asked by someone with 3k+ rep (which for me translates as interesting) only to find out it was edited by that user =/

Comment: Why only at a certain rep limit? Established User is 1000 rep. But you can start reviewing with 200 rep. And commenting above 50 rep. I don't see the need of user separation (maybe because I have less 1k rep)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This feature has been pushed out in build rev `2014.4.14.1545`. It was decided that the questions will have only `asked`, `answered` and `modified` (which also covers everything else - bounties, community bumps, etc) statuses on the home page. We didn't do a backfill, so you may still see some questions w/o a status on less active sites.

Comment: Looks good, thanks very much :)

Comment: [This](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/9111/43) post doesn't show any sign of being 'edited', but the front page [shows](http://i.stack.imgur.com/LRQrF.png): "modified 5h ago", is this a bug or is it because I deleted the post?

Comment: @JackDouglas it's [tag:status-bydesign], it was displayed as modified because you deleted an answer.

Comment: OK, but it said "modified 5h ago Chuck Riley" not "modified *1h* ago *Jack Douglas*" (I deleted it about 4 hours after it was posted.

Comment: We don't bump questions when answers are deleted. In order for it to say `whatever 1h ago by whomever` it would need a bump and `modified 5h ago by Jack Douglas` would also be wrong. Furthermore, we can't leave the `answered` text there because it too would be even more confusing + there's also the case of a question with deleted answers only. What we have now is basically the least of all possible evils :)

Comment: @m0q: is this behaviour coming soon the [questions/tagged/active](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-request?sort=active&pageSize=50) page? Currently all posts show "modified", even if the last activity was the question being asked/ answered.

Answer (score 13):

I have written a userscript for those who need this functionality.

[**Stack Activity**: Last activity of every question on the homepage](https://stackapps.com/questions/4134/stack-activity-last-activity-of-every-question-on-the-homepage)

> Here's a screenshot of Meta Stack Overflow with the userscript:
>
> [image: meta]