# A duplicated was created out my rollback

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, rollbacks

I proposed [a feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144935/more-descriptive-caption-to-active-questions-instead-of-just-modified), but it wasn't getting that popular so I decided to make a move: I edited the proposal, making it impossible to annoy the ones who don't want the feature (changed to only appear on mouse hover).

This didn't seem to gain more attention and got stuck at +3 votes. However, the edit allowed someone to post a *very* [similar question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145039/can-we-add-asked-answered-edited-text-to-each-question-featured-the-fron) to my original one getting +41 score.

It is obvious that my question is better without the tool-tip edit, so I did a rollback.

Now, what I want to discuss is:

- Which one is the duplicate now, my rollback or his question?
- What will happen now?

I don't want to replace a perfect +41 proposal with a +3 proposal, as this will be dumb for all of us (including me, who want to have this feature implemented).

**What can we possibly do to not replace gold with copper?** (or more accurately, don't stain gold with copper)

Also, the possibility to delete mine is slim, I am very afraid of the question ban thing (my life would end if that happened), and I think I have deleted a couple of posts in the past so I don't want to get any closer.

Comment: just for the record, I know the question ban is reversible, but my mind wouldn't be able to recover from such thing

Comment: Jack Douglas hit the sweet spot with his feature request: It is "Edited", "Asked", "Answered" that we want to see, and he even provided a prototype picture.  Don't be discouraged; I posted a feature request a couple of days ago that got a big "meh" from the community, but I'm not all that worried about it.  Just another day in meta paradise.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I am not discouraged or sad, I recognize he worded it better and got gold instead of copper. But what I am is _worried_, worried that the system take the wrong decisions here.

Comment: It's pretty hard to get perma-banned on Meta; the thresholds are set much lower here, in the interest of fairness and transparency (or something like that).

Comment: @RobertHarvey done http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/145116/179635 your words gave me confidence

Comment: @RobertHarvey - And [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/157251/evan-carroll) is the living proof of that statement.

Comment: I think once you've gained some rep you don't have to be afraid of being banned on Meta, but back when I had no rep at all, I asked a couple of bad questions and I got banned instantly. So @Robert, you may want to put that into perspective a bit.

Comment: I've never heard that gold/copper saying before, and I don't quite get what you're trying to say. Could you explain it another way?

Comment: @PopularDemand one is more valuable. I was going to use the mirror-gold thing that spain traded with native mexicans, but then mirror would be confused as a duplicate, so I switched to copper. Also the stain part is because we wouldn't be trading one question with other, it would be more like adding a dirty closed and dup link to one (hence stain instead of trade)

Answer (score 1):

It is done, I deleted my question for the good and prosperity of SE.

This convinced me:

> It's pretty hard to get perma-banned on Meta; the thresholds are set
>   much lower here
>   - Robert Harvey♦