# Can we show the 'asked', 'edited' and 'modified' text for the iOS app too?

Tags: feature-request, ios-app

This question is related to [Can we add 'asked', 'answered', 'edited' text to each question featured on the front page?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145039/can-we-add-asked-answered-edited-text-to-each-question-featured-on-the-f).

The feature request is to show this in the iOS app too.

Current design:

[image]

Comment: Plug in your phone! Quick!

Comment: And android app as well!

Comment: And "closed" status! Oh, fine, I'll make another request.

Comment: @Josh: it's visible in the title right?

Comment: In the app? No, I don't see any indicator until I open the question itself.