# Reopened questions get a "modified" time stamp in the questions list

Tags: bug, information-display, timestamps, question-lists, reopened-questions

[This question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/38089/1204) just showed up on [RPG.SE](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/)'s front page like this:

[image: Size of a campaign world? modified 4m ago CatLord 10.7k]

... which makes no sense, because the question hasn't been modified since May 25th, and the person who edited it wasn't CatLord anyway:

[image: screenshot of the edit stamp showing it edited by DCShannon]

Turns out what actually happened was that CatLord cast a fifth reopen vote to reopen the question.

[image: Post reopened 5 mins ago, with CatLord being the last person to vote to reopen]

So that stamp in the questions list should probably say this instead:

> reopened 4m ago CatLord 10.7k

Or just:

> reopened 4m ago

Comment: Probably by-design - I can't find the post at the moment, but I do believe one of the devs or CMs said that the only distinct labels were going to be "asked", "answered", and "modified" (which is a catch-all for every other type of change).

Comment: It's confusing as heck though, so if that's the case I guess I'll need to make this a feature request. I've seen questions with a 'modified' mark that had no edits at all or deleted answers, and I was scratching my head as to why so this is probably what was going on there.

Comment: I found the post for context, [it's here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/229665/152515): _"It was decided that the questions will have only asked, answered and modified (which also covers everything else [...])"_ Hm... I wonder if there's some way to make this less confusing.