# What does active mean?

Tags: support, questions, last-activity

In any post there are three attributes:

1. Asked
2. Viewed
3. Active

What is the meaning of the active in a post?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

"Active" shows when the post was last active. Active means that it has a change: an edit, an answer, an edit to an answer, bumped by Community♦ etc...

It might happen that the "last activity indicator" displays an activity which is nowhere to be seen. This can be the result of:

- an answer which has been deleted since then (spam/rude/not an answer etc);
- a bounty being set up;
- a closed question being reopened (last activity then reads `modified by whoeverCastedLastReopenVote`);
- the Community♦ user bumping the question so that its answer can be peer reviewed/accepted.

New comments don't make a question "active".

Comment: I think adding a bounty also affects this, but not sure (and not handing one out just to test :-) ).

Comment: @MonicaCellio true, starting a bounty is also considered activity on the question itself. However, awarding the bounty is not.

Comment: Also affecting activity is reopening: the user with the last reopen vote appears as the one who "modified" the question, which [might look confusing](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/233498/reopened-questions-get-a-modified-time-stamp-in-the-questions-list).