# Unanswered questions do not show Active time

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, questions, unanswered-questions, last-activity

Normally a post shows the active time after first edit.

[image: Under question title: “Asked today; Answered today; Viewed 10 times”]

[One post](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/239565/109190) of mine does not show that information, does that indicate the post is not a normal state? If yes, what it is?

[image: Under question title: “Asked 18 days ago; Viewed 108 times”]

Comment: That's odd. The post was last edited today and was made 18 days ago, so I don't see why it doesn't show (other than possibly caching - extreme caching, since the previous edit was two days ago).

Comment: @Sonic that's an almost obvious bug. If it's on purpose, I consider this a feature request to bring the "Active" back.

Comment: After quick check, looks like there's no "Active" anymore for any question without answers, regardless of the question age or activity.

Comment: There's some info under ***some*** of the questions for the [tag:active] tag (which has no Wiki Excerpt, and thus has been used for more than one purpose), one question is here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/242868/282094 --- There needs to be an activity that makes the question "active" for there to be a sentence at the top proclaiming that it was active. Exactly all the criteria seems to have changed, for example this question was edit five hours after being posted yet has *no activity*. So that's not quite an answer, more of adding to the mystery.

Answer (score 10):

The real mystery here is how nobody noticed that "active" timestamp has pretty much always only appeared on questions with at least one answer. :)

The original version of the sidebar back in 2008 included more stats about the answers, and that information was hidden for questions without any. Looks like over time, that gradually changed over to just hiding the last active date.

So, two things here:

1. Apparently it's not a bug and your post is fine.
2. It does seem like an oversight. I'll double-check with someone internally, but I suspect we'll be removing the answer count check here.

Thanks for the report!

---

**Update:** we're going to show the last activity timestamp on all questions starting with the next production build (> `rev 2020.4.1.36451` here on Meta).

Comment: Mismatch in what you say: if it's an oversight, it means it's a bug. No? Maybe very old and unnoticed, but still, something is working in a way that is different from the way it should be working.

Comment: @ShadowWizardisEarForYou It's working as it was designed, but I think we should change that design.