# What does [active] mean?

Tags: discussion, tags, meta, burninate-request

Inspired by [What does active mean?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/242868/295232) which had the very ambiguous [active](/questions/tagged/active) tag (thanks @Amplitwist for the edit). It has 19 questions but no tag excerpt. If you search in the [tag list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/) for `activ`, you'll notice that we have several more specific tags, one (or more) of which are likely to apply to each of those 19 questions:

[image]

Any objections to burninating this tag? I'll retitle this question "This tag is no longer [active]" after it's [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).

Comment: Alternate title: Do we still need this tag to be [active]

Comment: Alternative title: Trogdor has to become [active]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I don't have a preference, and once this question is no longer next to the inspiration, that joke is probably lost. Feel free to edit it to the highest-voted comment in a day or so.

Comment: I think it would be good to go ahead and burninate this tag. At the same time, perhaps there is some merit to having a tag named [active-tab]? We currently have [tag:bountied-tab], [tag:frequent-tab], [tag:hot-tab], and [tag:bugs-reqs-tab], to say nothing of the generic [tag:questions-tabs].

Comment: It could be merged with [**sorting**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/sorting/info), where "Active" is specifically mentioned. --- Alternative title: Actively inactivating [Active] --- No retitling necessary, after its sorte.