# Tag excerpts are not shown on the Tags page if the filter text is not empty

Tags: bug, tags, tags-page

Taking Meta Stack Exchange as an example (the same behaviour appears to be exhibited by all Stack Exchange sites), the Tags page for Meta Stack Exchange at https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags shows tag excerpts if the filter text is empty:

> [image]

whereas if the filter text is *not* empty, the excerpts are not shown:

> [image]

This appears to have started happening in the last year or so - in the Meta Stack Exchange question [What does [active] mean?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/375850/284827) from February 2022, there is a screenshot of the tag page with a filter where the excerpts are shown.

---

Reproduced with Firefox 111.0.1 and Edge 112.0.1722.34 on Windows 10, and Chrome 112.0.5615.47 on Android 13.

Comment: (I discovered this due to [this suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/33997667) on Stack Overflow).