# Edit made, but no edit shown

Tags: support, questions, edits

On the [Programmers.se](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/), an edit was made to [my post](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/285011/how-much-logging-is-necessary-in-log4j), which I can see on the hot questions list.

[image]

This edit was made by a Moderator (note the diamond) so it should be shown in my question, but when I go to the question itself, the edit is nowhere to be found.

[image]

Where is the expected edit to my question?  I don't think this is a problem with Programmers.se specifically, because this is the same question form that all SE sites use.

Comment: It was reopened: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/posts/285011/revisions which counts as a touch edit

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/233498/reopened-questions-get-a-modified-time-stamp-in-the-questions-list

Comment: @random It must have happened pretty fast - My question was less than 10 minutes old when I saw the edit, and I didn't even notice it was closed.

Comment: Just curious, why did you end up deleting it?

Comment: @ShadowWizard It turned out it was a duplicate of a topic that was already closed, and I couldn't think of anything I could do to make it more specific or answerable.  It also didn't seem that useful to leave it as a question that would eventually be closed.  I might try asking it from a different angle at a later day though.