# Change “modified” to a more descriptive word

Tags: feature-request, homepage, wording

On the [active](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=active) list, I would like to see more descriptive language used in place of "modified."

Instead of saying "modified N hours ago," it would be helpful if instead it said 
"**edited** N hours ago," 
"**retagged** N hours ago," 
"**asked** N hours ago," 
or "**answered** N hours ago."

(An additional feature could be the option to filter by the type of modification, e.g. to display only answers or only retags.)

Would others find this feature useful?

Comment: Related userscript: [Stack Activity: Last activity of every question on the homepage](http://stackapps.com/q/4134) (although it's for the homepage, instead of the active list)

Comment: Modified is a nice title indeed. It acts not only for 'edited' the question but also for 'retagged'. I agree with you. +1

Comment: @TimStone I am thinking of extending it to other lists. The codes should be similar but may take a while. I will make an update when I have completed it.

Comment: @TimStone It turns out to be easier than I have thought. [The script is updated](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/183179/209357) and it now works on the active tab as well.