# Recent activity bug (or feature)

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, recent-activity

The feature "Recent activity on the front page" has a subtle bug (or perhaps it is a feature): clicking on the link always takes you to he most recent activity which may not coincide with what's displaying on the front page.

For example,

> User A adds an answer. The front page says: "1m UserA"
>   If during that minute user B added another answer, clicking on the link "User A" will take you to the answer added by the user B

I have a video that may explain this better: [Recent activity bug on SO (engine)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3hwP2Nrrfp0&fmt=22).

**edit** Oops I cut too much from the start of the video. If you pause it one or two seconds in you can tell the link says: "5m George Stocker" and following the link takes you to Oscar Reyes' answer.

Comment: Ramble ramble ramble. At least when I don't stop writing I'm coherent and spell things correctly. I recognize that you might be from Elbownia or some other far-away mud-covered non-English-speaking country but that's not an excuse for rambling. It's certainly an excuse for spelling things strangely but not really in the way that you did. Anyway, unless you're from Rambland (the land of rambling) you should learn how to type as if you're writing and not as if you've just smoked a few too many lines of powdered milk and eaten a few too many handfuls of jelly beans. Seriously man. Stay in school.

Comment: @urd, I **am** from Rambland, we don't type like that

Comment: @Downvoter: Well, I'm from Super Mario Land and we have initiated trade with the government of Rambland and so I have taken the opportunity to improve my Ramblish (the official language of Rambland) because I'm hoping to go on vacation there for a few weeks or possibly open up a shop there that sells Super Mario Land's most famed export: super mushrooms that make you grow really, really tall and give you the ability to break floating bricks that happen to be over your head if you jump really high and also let you get hit by a paratroopa or other monster without instantly dying.

Comment: @urd, Well, great! You can stay at my house then; if you want, I can find investors for your shop, just forward me your account number, full name, and security code for me to know you mean serious business and I'm not wasting my time.

Comment: @urdnot : If spelling  correctly and writing  coherently would imply being from a far-away mud-covered English-Speaking country ( which  I suppose that's how SuperMario Land is ) and have stupid names and write stupid ( but coherent ) things like those you have written in the past, then I would rather stay in Rambland. In the other hand, thanks for the editing my question.

Comment: @Oscar: He's from Canada, so yeah.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

by design, since the link always goes to the most recent activity. Caching and leaving stale browser windows open will of course link to a 'different' recent activity.