# Add linking into activity action on Tag-filter

Tags: feature-request, tag-filters

On the tag-filter page on Stackexchange you can see the latest activity, for instance:[image] from [Stackexchange LabVIEW filter](https://stackexchange.com/filters/4353/labview).
However the activity moment is not a link. For the questions page of a site (for instance the [tag-page on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/labview?sort=active&pageSize=15)) you have active hyperlinks on the activity moment.
It would be usefull to have this on the tag-filter page as well. (extension of [this request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4391/add-link-to-most-recent-activity-of-a-question))