# Show last action in Top Questions on mobile site

Tags: feature-request, design, mobile-web, last-activity

Questions on the Top Questions list show the last action performed on them, as in the image:
[image]

I don't need to tell you why this feature is useful; you already know from experience. I find  it especially helpful when I am watching for answers to a question.

So far as I can find, this was first suggested [by TheTXI here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/14562/366373). Although this has feature has been around for a very long time, the mobile site does not have it. See the image below:

[image]

I think it would be really great to add this feature to the mobile site, where I often miss it. There is plenty of space to add it too, and I can't think that this would be *too* hard to implement, as it has been around on the desktop site for ages.