# What third-party tools are there for the trilogy websites?

Tags: support, faq, userscript, addon, third-party

What third-party tools, plugins, addons, widgets are there for the trilogy websites?

[Return to FAQ index](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/)

Comment: If you're here, you should likely check out [Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/) instead, Stack Exchange's site specifically devoted to supporting and hosting apps and scripts which integrate with Stack Exchange sites and the official Stack Exchange API.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

### List of Third-Party Tools

Note: These are NOT official applications, and are NOT officially sanctioned or supported.
Note: some of these are specific to Stack Overflow

#### GreaseMonkey scripts

- [Questions tagged greasemonkey](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/greasemonkey)
- [GreaseMonkey scripts: Edit summary quick links & Edit Summary must be filled in](http://blog.bogojoker.com/2008/09/stack-overflow-edit-summary-quicklinks/)
- [GreaseMonkey script: Track New Votes/Reputation.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12448/greasemonkey-users-here-is-your-vote-reputation-info-plug-in-for-stackoverflow)
- [GreaseMonkey script: Unread question and favorite tags highlight]†
- [GreaseMonkey script: Drag and Drop Tags to Ignored/Interesting lists](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/48179)
- [GreaseMonkey script: Ignore tag implementation for Greasemonkey users]†
- [GreaseMonkey script: Add "revisions" links and auto-expand comments](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/35942)
- [GreaseMonkey script: Keyboard Shortcuts for SO](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/50954)
- [GreaseMonkey script: Question Dashboard for Trilogy, StackExchange]†
- [GreaseMonkey script: Beautify the UI of StackOverflow a bit](http://userscripts.org./scripts/show/65674)
- [GreaseMonkey script: Add “reply” links to comments]†
- [GreaseMonkey script: Add “Save to Delicious” link to question]†
- [GreaseMonkey script: Commander Keen on downvote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34903/stack-overflows-voting-system-is-not-entertaining-enough/41397#41397)
- [GreaseMonkey script: Additional searchbox on question page for searching within the answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1274/seaching-questions-with-n-pages-of-answers/49338#49338)
- [GreaseMonkey script: Add “Printer-Friendly” link to question](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/77298)

#### Other

- [JetPack script: Reputation status](http://www.cznp.com/sojet/)
- [Flair on Facebook!!]†
- [Firefox & IE7 Stackoverflow Search Plugin]†
- [Stackoverflow Html Scraper]†
- [Track Your Reputation (Web Service)]†
- [StackOverflow Reputation Tracker (by Jon Skeet)](http://csharpindepth.com/StackOverflow/ReputationTracker.aspx)
- [Ubiquity script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31173/ubiquity-hack#35506)
- [Operator Script for tag search](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21759/operator-user-script-for-stack-overflow)
- [Firefox StackOverflow Toolbar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12397/firefox-stackoverflow-toolbar)
- [StackOverflow badge to show in your blog.](http://pietschsoft.com/post.aspx?id=36e89f5e-4e11-4a73-81c6-3dde5c757fba)
- [WordPress Widget for a "GamerTag" style display of your Gravatar/Name/Rep/Badges](http://www.grumpydev.com/2009/01/09/stack-overflow-wordpress-widget/)
- [WordPress Sidebar Plugin](http://picandocodigo.net/programacion/wordpress/stackoverflow-reputation-wordpress-plugin-english/)
- [A JSON data service to access your Stackoverflow rep + an easy to use JS widget](http://json-stackoverflow.appspot.com/)
- [User Rankings List]†
- [User Badge Service]†
- [Votes-Per-Tag Application (Desktop/WPF)]†
- Windows Sidebar Widget for Displaying Flair †
- [Android Flair Widget](http://www-jo.se/f.pfleger/soflair)
- [Mac OS X Dashboard Flair Widget](http://widget.huxhorn.de/)
- [iGoogle homepage Stackoverflow Gadget](http://www.google.com/ig/directory?hl=en&url=files.getdropbox.com%2Fu%2F10936%2FgadgetHosting%2FstackoverflowProfile%2Fprod%2Fstackoverflow.xml)
- [stackoverflowIndentFourSpaces - "Indent Four Spaces (for SO)"](http://wittman.org/projects/stackoverflowindentfourspaces/)
- [Chrome Extension Notifier]†
- [Another dashboard widget for Mac OS X](http://github.com/victor/stackoverflow-flair.dcproj)
- [Cross site newest and active question list]†
- [Code formatting assistance for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/dgkbnngeehclnibbdblaimapibmmcdal)

There is also a specific site for this: **[stackapps.com](http://stackapps.com)**, which has '[apps](https://stackapps.com/?tab=apps)' and '[scripts](https://stackapps.com/?tab=scripts)' tags.

Additional scripts can be found on [Userscripts.org](http://userscripts.org/) by searching for "[Stack Overflow](http://userscripts.org/scripts/search?q=stackoverflow)."

The use of the [so-addon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/so-addon?sort=votes) tag is encouraged for scripts, plug-ins, browser add-ons and other tools that are posted to Meta Stackoverflow.

† *Broken links that were deleted*

Comment: Many of the greasemonkey links are broken. :(

Answer (score 7):

I have just made a Windows Sidebar Gadget for Stack Overflow.
Take a [look here](http://insomniacgeek.com/code/windows-gadget/a-stack-overflow-sidebar-gadget/).

[image]

I have got some questions on whether it is possible two have multiple gadgets. Yes, that is possible. You can have multiple gadgets, for example like this (A Stack Overflow and a ServerFault gadget):

[image]

I have published the gadget with source code [on CodePlex](http://flairgadget.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Released v1.0.2.0 which brings the possibility to click on your displayname to go to your profile page.

Comment: Released v1.1.0.0 with support for ServerFault.com

Comment: Released v1.3.0.0 Adds support for SuperUser.com and Meta.StackOverflow.com. http://flairgadget.codeplex.com/

Comment: Now how about including the  SE 2.0 sites? I love your gadget, but I'm most active on Gaming.SE. ;)

Answer (score 2):

I've just finished a [StackOverflow.com Flair Widget](http://widget.huxhorn.de/) for the Mac OS X Dashboard.
It would be nice if you could include it in the list.

Does anyone have a positive answer to this question:
[Is there a AJAX or JSON interface to retrieve the stackoverflow.com userId for a given username?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/980396/is-there-a-ajax-or-json-interface-to-retrieve-the-stackoverflow-com-userid-for-a)

Comment: Hi, I'm just trying out your OS X widget for some days now and it always again happens that it resets the userid to yours. You probably don't notice it since you put your own as default, but try switching to some other id, just to test it. Unfortunately I did not yet figure out when this happens..

Comment: It happened to me once, too, but I don't know what caused the reset... I'd really appreciate more info if you find out what causes this... It's my first widget :p but I'll check.

Answer (score 0):

[StackOverflow.com Badge to display in your Blog](http://pietschsoft.com/post.aspx?id=36e89f5e-4e11-4a73-81c6-3dde5c757fba)

This is a user control written in ASP.NET, but could be easily converted for other server-side platforms, or even converted to JavaScript with the help of a JSON service.

Comment: Could you please add this to the list in the community wiki answer and delete this answer.

Comment: i'd add it...but the answer would still be there.

Comment: It says its ASP.NET code. Does that badge display on Mac and Linux boxes? On Apache-served pages?
If not, I'd rather see something a little more portable.

Comment: When served by a machine running ASP.NET (mostly Windows machine, but Linux servers can run it using MONO), it will produce HTML that is viewable by a browser running under any OS.

Answer (score 0):

#### Highlight comment on hover

Add the following CSS to Firefox's `userContent.css` file or add a [Stylish](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2108) rule and when the mouse is hovering over a comment it will be highlighted so it's easier to keep your place and match comments with names.

```
@-moz-document domain("stackoverflow.com") {
  .comment:hover                  { background-color: #E5E5E5 !important; }
  .comment:hover .accepted-answer { background-color: #D9F5D9 !important; }
  .comment:hover .owner-answer    { background-color: #D6E4EE !important; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- There's a [Facebook Stack Overflow Flair](http://apps.facebook.com/stackoverflow_badge/)
- There's a Stack Overflow rule for AutoPager ([Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/4925)) ([Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/mmgagnmbebdebebbcleklifnobamjonh)) ([Here](http://member-ap.teesoft.info/;jsessionid=965b93912f4ac5bcc5e18c77b227.instance1?page=192&oe=0&exp=0) and search "Stack Overflow") (IMO, the Stack Overflow rules are broken)

Answer (score 0):

**Trilogy Site Ranking - For those who need to know**

[Trilogy Site Ranking - For those who need to know](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43911/trilogy-site-ranking-for-those-who-need-to-know)