# Vista Sidebar Flair

Tags: discussion, flair

> **Duplicate:**
>   [What Third Party Tools Exist To Use With Stackoverflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5188/what-third-party-tools-exist-to-use-with-stackoverflow/5195#5195)

Thanks to [Magnus Johansson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3584/magnus-johansson), we now have a very nice-looking Sidebar Flair Gadget.

http://flairgadget.codeplex.com/

[image]

Comment: Dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5188/what-third-party-tools-exist-to-use-with-stackoverflow

Comment: Please CW this...You didn't even write the widget.

Comment: I didn't claim to write it. I think I made it rather clear who did. You *can* politely point out that I failed to CW this without assuming I'm trying to take credit for somebody else's work.

Comment: @Kyle, this is not a duplicate. It's an emphasis on a tool that somebody made. I had no idea it existed, and apparently other's hadn't either.

Comment: I can understand wanting to give it more attention, but you do have to realize that this is an exact duplicate of the answer in the "Third Party Tools" thread that the author posted.

Comment: We don't discuss meta on SO, so where else am I to discuss this tool, and the possibilities of others like it?

Comment: I would encourage the author to post their own topic. Or, since it's open-source, you could fork it and distribute your own. However, this post was neither, as you just copied the information that was already available elsewhere.

Comment: I was polite...I said please!!  I was concerned that you were trying to benefit from other people's work, not necessarily take credit for it.

Comment: Sorry, jjnguy - "You didn't even write the widget" sounded like you accused me of attempting to take credit for writing it. After discussing this with Kyle, I'm fine with this being closed. I don't want to cause any misunderstandings.

Answer (score 0):

Very cool!