# Firefox Stack Overflow Toolbar

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

You can follow development progress on Twitter: [@stack_o_bar](http://twitter.com/stack_o_bar)

There's a [Google Groups](http://groups.google.com/group/stackoverflow-bar) in place for discussion.

**New Developments**:

- The Stack Overflow Bar has been accepted into the public as of 24 April 2009.
- I finally caved in to some suggestions about posting the code and created a project on [Assembla](http://www.assembla.com): [StackOverflow Bar on Assembla.com](http://www.assembla.com/spaces/StackOverflowBar)
  With this project, I have included a ticket system. I was too busy to host it myself anyway. Please use the facilities provided to give me some feedback.

This bar is a search bar and offers quick access to some of the areas of SO:

1. One button to access the home page.
2. A search box, with history, to search Stack Overflow.
3. A button to access the "Ask Question" link.
4. 6 buttons to access "Newest", "Hot", "Votes", "Active", "Unanswered" and "User" areas.

Please get the Stack Overflow Bar:

- [version 0.1.2.305](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/9511)

I've begun to setup the [bar's site](http://guscarreno.blogspot.co.uk/p/stack-overflow-bar.html) and I've also created a Google Groups List ([Stack Overflow Bar](http://groups.google.com/group/stackoverflow-bar)) where we can initiate our discussions about this bar.
Both are quite in the beginning so please be gentle on the comments.

**To Do List:**

- Add notification with API calls.
- Correct common typos on the variations of "Stack Overflow".
- Implement a drop-down on buttons with the top 5 entries on that SO area.

Comment: Before I install anything, I at least would like to know:
1. That it won't harm my computer.
2. What it does.
3. What it looks like.
4. Why I would need it.

Care to elaborate? :)

Comment: Hope my edits clarify your doubts. And thanks for the reality check :)

Comment: Just tagging something not-a-question doesn't make it appropriate to post as a question. Obviously you could contrive a question in order to post this as an answer, but the fact of the matter is maybe it's more appropriate to post in a FAQ somewhere that it's appropriate.

Comment: Almost all of the 3rd party SO software was announced via a question and then linked into the sofaq. That's what I did. If you have some time you can look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18557/how-does-stackoverflow-work-the-official-faq#119670

Comment: Although I don't plan to use it, I think it's nice that you are building this out.  My one comment after seeing the image would be to replace the SO logo on each button with more meaningful ones.  Just my opinion...

Comment: @Jonathan: Well My idea is to get a proper design person to do that. I'm just a lousy programmer that's even worse at image stuff :)

Comment: Too bad I'm addicted to Google Chrome...

Comment: Thanks for posting the source.  I've deleted my post suggesting Phishing software.  Thanks for the effort in putting this together.  Congrats

Comment: @Peter Walke: No problem mate. And thanks about the delete. I still have loads of coding to do, but at least it's a start.

Comment: @Arjan van Bentem: Hummm, could you use the assembla issue track for this please. Many thanks!!

Comment: @Arjan van Bentem: errr, nevermind. You mean on THIS post, eheheheh

Comment: @Arjan van Bentem ARGHHH, I only now got what you wanted: Include automatic typo correction. Hummmm, could be doable for some common mistakes like StackOverlow, StackOverfow, etc... Now I gotcha :)

Comment: @GustavoCarreno, just stumbled across this and noticed that the `gcarreno.org` links are dead, and the last version was almost 4 years ago.  Any updating that can be done on this?

Comment: @LanceRoberts: I've been waiting for the Firefox IDE libraries to catch up with some non standard toolbar calls. I've got a new version on hold for the last 2 years. I've not given up on it.

Answer (score 19):

1. I could bookmark the homepage, but since I always have a stackoverflow page open I always have a link to the homepage available.
2. I don't need search history (I already get that for the search box in the upper right corner, or I can use Firefox's Awesomebar feature to find previously visited pages)
3. Again, the ask question link is on every page, or I could bookmark it. (with a keyword if I wanted fast access to it without having to take my fingers off the keyboard)
4. Again, I could bookmark whatever pages I want fast access to and put them on my bookmarks toolbar
5. Stackoverflow already highlights the search terms in search results.

So I don't really see the need for this extension. When would it come in useful? What does it do that isn't available already?

Either you've created something that is unnecessary or you've failed to adequately describe the value of it.

Comment: Creating unnecessary stuff is what we do for love!

Answer (score 10):

I think it's a bad idea to ask people to install a plugin without providing, at the very least:

- a description of what it does
- screenshots or some other indication of what the user should expect to see when it's installed
- a way to get it through formal channels (eg Firefox addons page)

Comment: Hope my edits clarify your doubts. And thanks for the reality check :)

Comment: Ok, I now think that I came through on all 3 of your suggestions.

Answer (score 4):

I don't much like toolbars in general, but providing some kind of browser integration could of course be handy. Still, why not just use the searchbar plugin that already exists, or perhaps write an [Ubiquity](http://labs.mozilla.com/2008/08/introducing-ubiquity/) command that's able to perform all the fancy SO-integration features you can think of?

Going through your ideas, here are my thoughts:

1. Pointless. This is what bookmarks are for, and we already have those.
2. Pointless. Firefox has a searchbar built in, and a SO plugin already exists for that.
3. That'd be useful. But I'd personally rather see it as an Ubiquity command than a toolbar
4. See above, partly solved by bookmarks, but could be handy as well - but I'd rather see it in Ubiquity than a toolbar

Comment: At the moment the bar is pretty much a Google bar look-a-like. Probably that's what's throwing people off. After I implement some SO-centric stuff, probably it will be more pleasant.

Comment: I still don't want a toolbar unless it adds something absolutely 100% essential. It takes up valuable screen space and clutters the browser. Firefox allows plenty of other ways to expose functionality. But of course that's just my opinion. :)

Answer (score 2):

Some suggestions:

1. I think making the last search result a button is a bad idea. Just use the history in the drop down list.
2. The toolbar might be more useful if it opened new tabs, or at least had the option, maybe a checkbox on the toolbar.
3. Add an item to the right-click context menu to search a highlighted term on Stack Overflow. Again, open it in a new tab.
4. Maybe have a "Favorites" button, and an option to save a question as a favorite question in the toolbar. And/or have an option in the Add-Ons preferences for a username, and display a list of the Stack Overflow favorites from the profile.
5. Make the *Newest*, *Hot*, etc. buttons with optional dropdown lists that will display the top X number of questions for that option.

Comment: Those are all good features. Added to the todo list.

Answer (score 2):

I would love it if it does..

- tell me how many new questions there are since I last looked, for specific tags I choose. (ie. Delphi(3), C++(123) C#(313413342344),...)
- notifies me if there're new answers to my question (as well as the comments).

Comment: The notifications that I'm planning on doing will have all of this. It's going to be a bit further down the road since it's a bit more complicated to deal with local data.

Answer (score 1):

I always look at questions tagged for some particular language like C++ or Java" or include both. New/Hot/Unanswered mean New/Hot/Unanswered in a particular language. Do I have an option for that?

Comment: No. Added to the todo list.