# Should we burn this [browser-enhancement]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, meta, burninate-request

The [browser-enhancement](/questions/tagged/browser-enhancement) has 32 questions, no tag wiki or excerpt.  A quarter of those are questions about Greasemonkey scripts that have been closed and should've been posted on [StackApps](https://stackapps.com).  For those questions, plugins,  and scripts, we have the [addon](/questions/tagged/addon) and [userscript](/questions/tagged/userscript) tags, which *do* have specific excerpts that would prevent users from using them incorrectly.  A few of those questions look like they could do without them entirely.

Should we burn it?  Or synonymize [addon](/questions/tagged/addon) and [userscript](/questions/tagged/userscript) to it, with a new excerpt?

Comment: This tag is... gibberish; it could mean "enhance the browser", like a feature request, it could mean the question refers to a browser feature, which isn't on topic, it could mean userscript development, which you already covered... I don't understand what it's supposed to mean. Looks like it was originally created for that last case, if it was created for [the oldest question tagged with it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12397/firefox-stack-overflow-toolbar). I vote burn away.

Comment: Yes, we should burn it.

Comment: Burned! ..and I was sort of looking forward to checking out those grease monkey scripts..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The [browser-enhancement](/questions/tagged/browser-enhancement) tag has been removed from all 32 questions and will be gone within 24 hours.  As is becoming the norm with [burninate-request](/questions/tagged/burninate-request)s, here's a record of what moderation actions were taken during the burnination (AFAIK) either by diamond moderators, staff members, or just regular users:

### Deletion

- **5** questions were deleted (10K only):  [1,](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23314) [2,](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11036) [3,](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23656) [4,](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/259247) [5.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10560)

### Closure

- **7** questions were closed:  [1,](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25397) [2,](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49205) [3,](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89378) [4,](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20283) [5,](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21717) [6,](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2542) [7.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75081)

Thanks to Spevacus, Rob, Ryan and all the community members (and staff members) that helped out with this burnination!

[image: waffles]