# Should third party tools thread link be added to the FAQ?

Tags: feature-request

I don't know how many users of the SO Trilogy follow Meta to stay up to date, ask and talk about SO; not many, I guess.

In my opinion, a direct link to [Third party tools list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5188/what-third-party-tools-are-there-for-the-trilogy-websites) link should be added to the FAQ because it points to a lot of tools that add a great value to the Stack Overflow experience ([Commander Keen downvote Über Alles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34903/stack-overflows-voting-system-is-not-entertaining-enough/41397#41397)).

With Official APIs, there will be a fresh load of third party stuff out there; i think it would be correct to give it the right visibility.

Third party developers, please UPVOTE!

Next problem: do Stack Overflow trilogy users, who do not follow Meta, read at least the FAQ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it is part of the FAQ, because it is tagged as `faq`.

You are right, only people finding the link to Meta can read posts tagged with `faq`, but that's a minor problem. Because, no, the users do not read the FAQ. And the amount of users reading the FAQ decreases, the longer the FAQ will get ("OMG, ALL THIS TEXT!!!1!! WHO SHOULD READ THAT???).

Therefore I am against your suggestion.

Comment: It's part of the Faq but you get there just in case you read the last sentence of the faq that says: "If you're looking for excruciating detail, we host a section of constantly evolving FAQs that document everything about the site." then you need to click on the second page looking for something that you don't even know to exist.TOO MUCH also for the most diligent user :).

Answer (score -1):

I found the FAQ just fine, thank you very much. No searching or digging here.

As for third party goodies - sure, why not?

Comment: @sys: a profile like mine?

Comment: actually i don't get your answer :).Do you agree with my request or not?

Comment: I think the question has changed since I answered it - or I was confused - or something...