# Autovoting algorithm

Tags: feature-request, voting, fun

I have given the SO engine a year and half worth of my opinion. Upvotes, downvotes, it's become so banal.

I'm tired of expressing my opinion. I feel like those old guys in the balcony of the muppet show saying the same thing over and over again.

Can't SO just infer the way I would vote on a question/answer and do it for me?

Comment: Is it Friday already?

Comment: My Recent Activity says it is.

Comment: Nah, we don't need auto-voting.  Just voting that's [more entertaining](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34903/stack-overflows-voting-system-is-not-entertaining-enough).

Comment: @Aar: make sure you try out [the greasemonkey script](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34903/stack-overflows-voting-system-is-not-entertaining-enough/41397#41397). CKFTW!

Comment: This had a chance as a Friday post, but suit yourself.

Comment: @Jon I didn't know Friday posts were special around here. Would it make me cool or something? I want to be cool! Tag re-added.

Answer (score 9):

Just because I'm so nice, I've written a greasemonkey script for you... It features an incredibly advanced prediction engine that not only uses your previous voting history, posting history and viewing history, but also taps into things like your current mood (based off mouse movement tracking and keyboard use), room temperature, global political situations, ever-changing meta-memes and current bladder status. It also has a genetic algorithm that ensures that it continually gets more accurate the more you use it. So what are you waiting for? Install it & start browsing!

**The code**:

```
(function() {
    function GM_wait() {
        if (typeof unsafeWindow.jQuery == 'undefined') { 
            window.setTimeout(GM_wait,100); 
        } else { 
            $ = unsafeWindow.jQuery; letsJQuery(); 
        }
    }
    GM_wait();
    function letsJQuery() {
        $(function() { $(".answer, #question").filter(":has(.user-details > a:contains('Alconja'))").find(".vote-up-off:not(.vote-up-on)").click(); });
    }
})();
```

Make sure you install it against `http://meta.stackoverflow.com/*` and `http://stackoverflow.com/*`.

Comment: Hey, it works! lol

Comment: Excellent... looks like someone's already installed it. :)

Comment: Perfect way to trigger the fraud script and get all past and future upvotes for you nullified.

Comment: @Gnome: Doesn't that only happen if all the votes come from the same user?  You'd have to post in a lot of questions to trigger the vote fraud detection...

Comment: @Gnome - I do realise that... I was assuming it was pretty obvious that this was a joke & that no one would actually try & use it.

Comment: @Aarobot - That's actually a good point. I'd assumed it would definitely create fraudy behaviour, but given that I've only made ~150 posts across SO & Meta, its pretty unlikely that someone would see enough of them in a short enough period to trigger the fraud detection. So long as they weren't explicitly browsing my history and especially if they continued voting normally in the mean time.

Comment: -1 the line is too long to read on the iPad. Joke lost. And I stopped using Netscape Navigator in the 90s.

Comment: Now that I can scroll the line, I have to agree that this is funny. +2.

Answer (score 4):

No. There are so many factors that it would be impossible to write an all-encompassing algorithm. Here are just a few of them

- post lengths
- spelling and grammar
- your mood
- interest to you
- your previous knowledge of the author's skill (and his reputation)
- <sub>[irrelevant to put this here as a bullet point](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/Change_Article_Title.aspx)</sub>

Besides, it's not a lot of work, and it's how you can give back to the community. It requires very little from you, and means a lot to those who receive it.

Comment: oh you made my day with that bullet point joke. i even voted you up using my own finger.

Answer (score 2):

That'd be nice, but we should probably go all the way. Why do I need to type in answers manually when SO can just extrapolate what I would've written?

Comment: [Flack Overstow](http://stackapps.com/questions/306/flack-overstow-generate-spam-from-trilogy-posts) will make answers based on your previous answers... but I wouldn't hold my breath on getting any upvotes from them :)

Comment: Well, you know, I was just being realistic and all. An upvote/novote/downvote decision could be done with a Bayesian inference engine if you captured the right/enough dimensions. That said, I think most answers on SO take the form of "Dup of XXX" these days. So I guess that's an easy answer to autogen and could also be done with the inference engine.

Comment: Some days when I'm busy/lazy I just rerun the "best of Aaronaught" - so far nobody's noticed.

Answer (score 2):

No, the algorithm is simple.

Search for all high ranking posts that haven't been shut down and converted to community wiki yet.

Upvote the question.

Upvote the top answer.

Search the the top 5 answers and x-ref a database of funny/witty/pun phrases for matches, if found add a comment quoting it - for guaranteed 10+ upvoted comment.

Then select and upvote one of top ranking comments from each of the the first 5 answers.

I call it the RepWhoreBot

Comment: And... this was more of a joke. If you look at a lot of the top-ranking questions, you'll start to see a pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Only if you can't pass the Turing test.

Now, I have my suspicions about a few users, but...