# How to vent on Stack Overflow without resorting to personal attacks of character

Tags: discussion, fun

Sometimes voting down an answer or question just isn't satisfying enough psychologically. One feels the urge to annihilate and destroy with prejudice. However, there is no need for personal attacks on Stack Overflow.

Instead, make use of this **[bookmarklet](http://erkie.github.com/)** by Erik Rothoff and destroy, destroy, destroy:

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

(obviously no permanent damage is done, and you'll feel much more relaxed afterward)

Comment: This is a duplicate of my question about Chrono Trigger. This should be posted as an answer there! http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34903/stack-overflows-voting-system-is-not-entertaining-enough

Answer (score 3):

I'm sure everyone has felt like that at times, but have we that little self-control?

---

**Other concerns:** What happens if you vent on one of Jon Skeet's posts? Does your PC blow up? What if you use an iPhone?

Comment: but you just cant vent on Jon Skeets posts! The bookmarklet will just blow itself up if you try!! :-)

Comment: You will get one either way.