# Stack Overflow desktop notifier

Tags: support, stack-overflow, client

Is there any desktop notifier for stackoverflow.com?

I'd like it to notify in the system tray when questions of my interest are posted, answers and comments to my questions are given, etc.

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5188/what-third-party-tools-exist-to-use-with-stackoverflow

Comment: Also, this tool: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44545/trilogy-addicts-get-real-time-notifications-of-new-questions could help with a part of your need.

Comment: There's also SENotifier which works on OS X - http://stackapps.com/questions/3081/senotifier-a-stack-exchange-inbox-notifier-for-mac-os-x :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can find a list of desktop apps by [searching on Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/search?q=desktop):

- [StackApplet - Bringing Stack Exchange Notifications to Your Desktop](https://stackapps.com/q/83/3669)
- [StackTracker - Cross-platform desktop notification app](https://stackapps.com/q/290/3669)
- [Stack Notifier - Chrome extension for desktop notifications](https://stackapps.com/q/4400/22475)

Check also the [notifier tag](https://stackapps.com/questions/tagged/notifier).

Comment: Which one works best? I tried StackApplet and my experience is bad. It need 2-3 times authorization every day.

Comment: StackApplet is essentially abandonware. It isn't as useful as it once was and the amount of effort required to get it working again just isn't worth it.

Answer (score 3):

I've designed an app for this. It will show you live desktop alerts for new questions. It's made with VB.NET for Windows. You can find it [on stackapps](https://stackapps.com/questions/3982/live-desktop-alert-for-stackoverflow).

*Note: I am the developer of this product*

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to mention that the chat rooms have web notifications you can enable for new chat messages.

[image]

But for Stack Exchange updated answers and comments it's way too hard for the Stack Exchange developers to add.

Comment: Why is it too hard? They don't want to spend the time I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Any RSS reader/ notifier should do. I use [yarssr](http://yarssr.sourceforge.net/)  on Gnome and it works pretty well.