# Desktop application for Stack Overflow

Tags: support, notifications

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Stack Overflow desktop notifier](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47750/stack-overflow-desktop-notifier)

Are there any desktop applications available for Stack Overflow?

Comment: er, Google Chrome?

Comment: Hey. I'm working currently on [Stack Overflow App](https://github.com/Maqsim/stackoverflow-app) and also you can watch my streams [here](https://www.livecoding.tv/max_diachenko/). Some activity is welcomed star project, share with your friend and watch my streams and we will build an awesome app with all you.

Answer (score 4):

Please have a look at [Stack Apps](http://stackapps.com).

Search around and see if there is an existing app.  If not, perhaps you could post requesting one and someone might oblige, you never know.

> If your question is about …
>
> - the Stack Exchange API
> - applications built on the Stack Exchange API
> - scripts or browser extensions that work with Stack Exchange sites
>
> … it is welcome here.

Answer (score 3):

There are [StackTracker](https://github.com/swanson/stacktracker), which is multi-platform, and [StackApplet](https://launchpad.net/stackapplet), just to name two.