# How does a 'User was removed' affect on my reputation?

Tags: discussion, reputation, deleted-accounts

First have a look at my [reputation page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/298224/manetsus?tab=reputation).

I started with 1 basic reputation point. Then I got +100 from the association bonus. So my total reputation became 1 + 100 = 101.

Then I [edited](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/40232) one post and earned 2 more reputation points. So, my reputation became 101 + 2 = 103.

Then, on Oct 26, 2 reputation points were deducted with the reason "*User was removed*". But the [post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47750/stack-overflow-desktop-notifier/95751#95751) is still as it is and the writer of the post also still exists.

Why was my account affected because of that unknown user removed?