# Get Desktop Notification for achievements and Inbox

Tags: discussion

Would it be possible to get a desktop notification for achievements and the inbox for Stack Overflow?

To get

- Desktop/ browser notification

For

- Achievements reputation
- Inbox messages

Comment: @Laurel Partially only email part what about desktop/ browser notification

Comment: [Related](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/321093/now-that-the-mobile-apps-are-no-longer-in-development-could-we-get-web-push) though it is a little more detailed.

Comment: Try this for desktop notifications: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/47750/323179

Comment: @Laurel I tried this https://stackapps.com/questions/83/stackapplet-bringing-stack-exchange-notifications-to-your-desktop-large-scale not working.

Comment: I think proper [notification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification) support would be quite useful for some people. If you could edit your question to remove the part about email (since it's already supported), or perhaps ask a new question about desktop notifications only, I think you might get more support and people won't try to close this question as a duplicate.

Comment: @KodosJohnson Yes you are right  email part is removed

Comment: @robert-longson it doesn't gives achievement reputation notification. Can you reopen this ?