# Could the app-request tag be made an official one and featured on the front page as 'app-requests' tab?

Tags: feature-request, tags, stackapps

There is still some disagreement regarding the [desired scope and direction](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55163/area-51-site-proposal-stackexchange-api-application-development) of Stack Apps, [apparently](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55163/area-51-site-proposal-stackexchange-api-application-development/55171#55171), between parts of the app developer community and the *Stack Exchange Pantheon* (a great phrase coined by Dave Swersky in his question [Are there any restrictions on using icons/look-and-feel from the site(s)?](https://stackapps.com/questions/959), IMHO :)

I don't want to argue this complicated issue here, but rather propose and extend [Daves suggestion](https://stackapps.com/questions/980/is-stack-apps-the-place-to-suggest-applications/984#984):

Could [app-request](https://stackapps.com/questions/tagged/app-request) become an official tag featured on the front page as *app-requests*, just like the [app](https://stackapps.com/questions/tagged/app) tag is featured via the [apps tab](https://stackapps.com/?tab=apps)? This would improve one part of the issue considerably already I think, and match nicely with Jeffs request to [change stackapps and improve it to meet the intended role](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55163/area-51-site-proposal-stackexchange-api-application-development/55171#55171).

If you do agree, please vote on [Daves suggestion](https://stackapps.com/questions/980/is-stack-apps-the-place-to-suggest-applications/984#984) too, his cool tag name pin pointed the issue!

Comment: I'm hoping StackApps becomes a site intended for the technical aspects of the API and that [StackList](http://stacklist.quickmediasolutions.com/) becomes a user-friendly way to browse the apps that have been created.

Answer (score -1):

I see this got moved to Meta.

Now would be a great time to share my opinion:

- **StackApps:** for API support *and app-requests*
- **[StackList](http://stacklist.quickmediasolutions.com):** for listing apps