# Add in-page searching?

Tags: feature-request, answers, search, usability

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Seaching Questions with n-Pages of Answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1274/seaching-questions-with-n-pages-of-answers)

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> <kbd>F</kbd> works, but when there's 5+ pages it gets too much work. So add in-page (question) search to that first #sidebar.module or somekind of link which appends question ID to search bar. There's a lot of questions which have same kind of answers to same web sites etc.

Also I've seen on some sites this "infinite scroll" which loads new content when scrollbar hits bottom of scrollable area. This might be alternative for page numbers.

A bit related to search also is that when you're writing answer the engine would scan other answers for same URLs / words and giving suggestion box like "This URL is already mentioned in this question answers".

Answer (score 0):

Yes, In question searches for multi-page questions would be great.