# Search within the answers to a question

Tags: discussion, search

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Seaching Questions with n-Pages of Answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1274/seaching-questions-with-n-pages-of-answers)

I'm at one of those huge community wiki questions that ask for one suggestion per answer, and which already has tons of answers. Is there a way to do a search the answers to check if my suggestion already exists? I'd rather not manually check each of the 100+ answers if I can help it.

Couldn't find a way to do this from the examples posted [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search). Is there a way to perform such a search?

Comment: Dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1274/seaching-questions-with-n-pages-of-answers

Comment: If you don't care to read all these answers, why should someone care to read yours?

Comment: Really, who said that this has be a reciprocal arrangement? The question I'm talking about was to do with "Must Have" Mac software - I *know* what software I need, and I don't need to read all these answers thank you. Someone who's just starting out on a Mac would care to read my answer. Does that sound unreasonable?