# Searching inside a question

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, search

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Searching Questions with n-Pages of Answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1274/searching-questions-with-n-pages-of-answers)

Searching inside a question

Is it possible (and wouldn't it be a neat feature if not possible) to search inside a question.

For instance I was looking at

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711?sort=votes&page=1#sort-top

And was curious is x book was in there. But how do I search for that book inside this question?

I tried going to the main search bar and putting the title of the question and the title of the book but that did no return what I expected (had other posts).

Answer (score 8):

Probably duplicate: [Searching Questions with n-Pages of Answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1274/seaching-questions-with-n-pages-of-answers)

However, I answer because I think this could be made possible in a different way than proposed in that question.  Given the new search features ,why not allow us to provide the question ID in the regular search box:

`question:1711 "code complete"`

Would search on posts where `postId` = x or `parentId` = x.

Answer (score 2):

In most cases you can Ctrl+F to find something in the answers. There are very few questions with more than one or two pages of answers, which I think makes this feature only useful in a handful of cases.

Answer (score 0):

If the SO search fails you, you could always use Google. Just add "site:stackoverflow.com" to your query to filter results down to SO.

Answer (score 0):

For older questions you can write an sql query for the community dataset, which is easily accessible via http://data.stackexchange.com