# UI Element for "Search for answer inside this question"

Tags: feature-request, search

Related to [24354](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24354/searching-inside-a-question) and [1274](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1274/seaching-questions-with-n-pages-of-answers)

I recently wanted to find the best mouse gesture software for Windows, so I went to Superuser.com and found a [relevant question](https://superuser.com/search?q=gesture&tab=votes) quickly, but then had to flip through 5 pages to find the [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1241/what-are-some-must-have-windows-programs/1630#1630) that I was looking for. Afterwards I did find the [inquestion:this](https://superuser.com/search#advanced-search) advanced search option which was added [two months ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1274/seaching-questions-with-n-pages-of-answers/1441#1441) but is not very intuitive.

There are getting to be more and more poll-like questions that have answers that span multiple pages. [This query](http://odata.stackexchange.com/superuser/q/6039/displays-number-of-questions-with-high-answer-count) shows that there are about 51 questions on Superuser that do not fit on one page, and many more on Meta/SO/SF. The fact that these questions show up in search results can be confusing when you load the page and the search term is buried on the 2nd or 3rd page.

As the software is moving into areas with less technical expertise I think that adding a UI element to search for an answer inside of a question would be very helpful. Alternatively when visiting a question from the search page you could land on the page that includes the keywords that you searched for, such as page 5 in the above example.

Also, as a side note: It appears that answers after the first page are not being indexed by Google. [This query](http://www.google.com/search?q=strokeit+site:superuser.com) does not include the "What are some “must have” Windows programs?" question from the above example.

Answer (score 2):

> There are getting to be more and more poll-like questions that have answers that span multiple pages. This query shows that there are about 51 questions on Superuser that do not fit on one page, and many more on Meta/SO/SF. The fact that these questions show up in search results can be confusing when you load the page and the search term is buried on the 2nd or 3rd page.

51 out of 44261 total questions, or slightly over **one tenth of a percent** of all questions on Super User at the time I write this.

On Stack Overflow, there are roughly 16 * 50 = ~800 questions of this size, out of 770477. That is also about **one tenth of a percent** of all questions.

Since the advanced search operator `inquestion:` already exists, and we're talking about something that happens less than one tenth of a percent of the time, I am not sure what else needs to be done.

(on top of that, we actually don't encourage such questions -- it's more fair to say they are *tolerated* when the community allows them)

Comment: I did not know that poll questions were discouraged, and the inquestion operator does makes this problem "tolerable" so maybe you are right. It is important to note that even though they make up 1/10th a percent of questions they get 1-2% of Aggregate Total Views, so potentially 1 out of 50 question views have this problem. Also with the extra pages not being indexed by Google there could be more hits, especially on questions like the above example where the extra pages have valuable information.