# Is it possible to search responses before responding?

Tags: feature-request, search, answers, responses

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Searching Questions with n-Pages of Answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1274/searching-questions-with-n-pages-of-answers)

When preparing to post a response, especially a question that already has a lot of answers, is there a means of searching the responses to make sure I'm not duplicating an answer?

Comment: Dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1274/seaching-questions-with-n-pages-of-answers

Answer (score 1):

There is the `inquestion:this` search filter. Use your browser's duplicate (tab) feature to keep your answer in place and then you can search (once) using this filter.