# Is there a way to search the answers of a Question?

Tags: support, answers, search

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Seaching Questions with n-Pages of Answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1274/seaching-questions-with-n-pages-of-answers)

Is there a way?
I first thought about this with those 'best X' questions as I'd rather up-vote an answer that was already given rather than add another of the same answer.
It might also be useful for more 'regular' questions, if I had a very specific case and the top answers didn't address it. It might be nice to search the answers of a question instead of paging through.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1274/seaching-questions-with-n-pages-of-answers