# Another Search-Constraint, "Question"?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, search

Regarding [Searching Questions with n pages of answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1274/seaching-questions-with-n-pages-of-answers), allowing us to constrain search results to a particular question would solve this immediately without requiring much more work on the development team's end. Just as `user:130154` limits all results to my posts, `question:48105` could limit results to answers for that particular question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, this is implemented, see

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search

Comment: @Jeff, my good man, you deserve a vacation ;)

Comment: An example: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=inquestion%3A9134+matrix Nice.