# Allow me to have all answers on 1 page

Tags: discussion, feature-request, answers

On the newest questions page there is an option regarding how many items to show at once. However this option doesn't exist for questions. What I propose is that we be able to select how many we want to display, just like we do on the newest questions page. I would also like to add to the ability to **have all answers on a single page**.

The main reasoning behind having all answers on a single page is so that I can quickly search the data versus doing a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> on each page, and then repeating that same search for however many pages there are.

Take for example [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/47197/are-there-any-famous-one-man-army-programmers): If I want to see if Jeff Atwood has already been added to the list, I must use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> a minimum of 4 times.

I believe this would make searching much easier while also **cutting down on duplicate answers**.

Comment: see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search

Comment: @Jeff: I really like the search and I'll defiantly start using it. It seems like it has been really improved.

Comment: (The `inquestion` is not a new option, @Dexter.)

Comment: @Arjan: The blog says that it is a new feature: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/stack-overflow-search-now-61-less-crappy/

Comment: Well, in 2009 the `inquestion:` option wasn't there yet. What exactly in that (old) blog are you referring to? (Introduced [in May 2010](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1274/searching-questions-with-n-pages-of-answers/1441#1441).)

Comment: @Arjan: You said `"inquestion is not a new option"`. I was saying that it was a new option. It's new as of May 2010.

Comment: Sure, @Dexter, if that's the way you think, then everything is new ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can search a question like this:

> inquestion:this *your search*